# Empirical mean optimal mean square error, Gaussian is the worst case.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

I have started reading [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annales-de-linstitut-henri-poincare-probabilites-et-statistiques/volume-48/issue-4/Challenging-the-empirical-mean-and-empirical-variance--A-deviation/10.1214/11-AIHP454.full) paper, and do not understand a line in its first paragraph in the introduction. He says:

> Indeed, as far as the mean square error is concerned, Gaussian distributions represent already the worst case, so that in the framework of a minimax mean least square analysis, no need is felt to improve estimators for non-Gaussian sample distributions.

So far I know that in the non-parametric setting, the sample mean is a minimax estimator of the expected value of a random variable when using the squared loss, for the class of distributions with finite variance (see Bickel and Doksum,
2015, Example 3.3.4).

But, I do not understand what he means by "Gaussian distributions already represent the worst case".